# Regex for conditional tag for a custom post type with numbers

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, conditionaltagsupport

I am using a plugin that creates question pages. The URL for each page looks like this:
example.com/?question_441

I want to add an action to all question pages and I'm trying to do it with conditional tags.
The following conditional tag works specifically with question_441:

> if ('question_441' == get_post_type())

However, I would like it to work with all question pages. I tried the following:

> if ('question_'.'[0-9]' == get_post_type())

but it won't work. Can anyone tell me the correct concatenation and regex for this.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
if (preg_match('/question\_[0-9]+/', get_post_type()))
```